# Draw new UIImage from old UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiimage

i have an UIImage like bellow 
[image]

i want to draw a new image from the bove image like video icon and video duration
[image]

**can any one help to draw code like above or refer any blog thx.. in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a UIImageView *myImage, you can do this:

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)];
myLabel.text = yourString;
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.2];

[myImage addSubView:myLabel];

[myLabel release];
```

Hope i understood your question.

Answer (score 1):

But still, if you want to display the image in the iphone like a preview screen or something, just create a custom uiview with 2 uiimageview for the image and the camera thingy with the bottom border, and one textlable for the duration. then you can jut update this label depending on the duration of whatever image/video duration.